# Ubuntu 23.10 + HP ( 3F0 Error, PXE-E61 error )

Tags: 23.10

I tried to Install Ubuntu 23.10 desktop on a used HP Elitebook G1 I just bought.
I downloaded The Ubuntu to a external 1 TB hard disk. The computer had Windows 10 installed on it before I tried to install Ubuntu btw.
So I tried to install Ubuntu by resbooting the computer. I chose I
then rebooted the computer and after Installing Ubuntu, It asked me to restart. After restart I got the errors "Hard Disk 3F0 Error" and "PXE-E61" And now I have tried almost everything... I changed the settings to Legacy and default Bios, But I still have the same problem.

I have watched videos and searched google for solutions for days! Please help.

Comment: Ubuntu will not fit on a "1 GB hard disk"

Comment: Sorry I meant 1TB